# Change main title color of navigation in MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I haven't problem for change color of main title of navigation on a normal viewController but on a MFMailComposeViewController, it isn't possible.
I can change colors of buttons (cancel and send), I can set background of navigation bar but not possible to change color of title. I don't want set a new title (apparently, it's not allow by Apple), I just want change the color :'(

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Refer to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634417/changing-mfmailcomposeviewcontrollers-toolbar-color

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *navbarTitleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                            [UIColor whiteColor],UITextAttributeTextColor, 
                                            [UIColor blackColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, 
                                            [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(-1, 0)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset, nil];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:navbarTitleTextAttributes];
```

Or

```
navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor yellowColor] forKey:UITextAttributeTextColor];
```

Hope its work for you..

Comment: This changes color throughout the app but not in  MFMailComposure. IOS 12.

Answer (score 15):

**This is the correct answer for iOS 7, 8, 9, and 10:**

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[[picker navigationBar] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor blackColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName]];
```

**Here is why:**

The check marked answer above (by Mani) referencing `[UINavigationBar appearance]` is incorrect as it will change the color of the title in the `UINavigationBar` that is popping the `MFMailComposeViewController` as well, which was an effect I didn't want. You need to specifically get the picker's NavBar as my code does.

Setting `tintColor` is also incorrect as of iOS 7 (the other answer by Mani) as it sets the colors of the buttons, not the title.

Also, `UITextAttributeTextColor` is now deprecated, please use `NSForegroundColorAttributeName`.

Answer (score 10):

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [[picker navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Comment: It's not what I search, here you change the color of navigation bar (I've already a background for that), I want to change the color of titleview

Answer (score 0):

For colors other than black, play around with this code:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailController  = [MFMailComposeViewController new];

            [mailController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithHue:240.0f/359.0f
                                                                  saturation:85.0f/100.0f 
                                                                  brightness:60.0f/100.0f 
                                                                       alpha:0.0f]];
```