# MFMailComposeViewController bar background color not changing in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios7

I'm trying to **change the background color** of the `MFMailComposeViewController` in **iOS7** but I cannot make it work.

I'm using the following snipped:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

if([picker.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(barTintColor)]) {
    // iOS7
    picker.navigationBar.barTintColor = READER_NAVIGATION_BAR_BACKGROUND_COLOR;
    // Set back button arrow color
    [picker.navigationBar setTintColor:READER_NAVIGATION_BAR_BACK_BUTTON_ARROW_COLOR];

    // Set Navigation Bar Title Color
    [picker.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:READER_NAVIGATION_BAR_TITLE_NORMAL_FONT_COLOR forKey:UITextAttributeTextColor]];

    // Set back button color
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:READER_NAVIGATION_BAR_BUTTONS_FONT_COLOR, UITextAttributeTextColor,nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Does anybody knows how to change the bakcground color of the `MFMailComposeViewController` in iOS7?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

try this. worked for me.

```
MFMailComposeViewController* myailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
// set other attributes of mailcomposer here.
myMailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;

[myMailViewController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

[self presentViewController:myMmailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this doesn't work neither... it does work for iOS6 but not for iOS7 which is what I'm looking for.

Comment: try this in the viewcontroller where your calling the mail composer [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

Comment: On iOS 9.2.1 I tested `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];` which didn't work for me. I had to use `[myMailViewController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];` which now is working again on this iOS version.

Answer (score 71):

The trick here is to call 'appearance methods' such as

```
[UINavigationBar appearance].barTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[UINavigationBar appearance].tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

**BEFORE calling to**

```
[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
```

This way the color scheme will be applied to the mail composer.
It may be returned back to defaults in `mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:`

Comment: damn the BEFORE is important here!

Comment: For iOS 7.0 and above, it appears this is the correct solution.  Also, you may need to call the same barTintColor and tintColor methods after the init to set them back to original colors of your app.

Comment: The downside to this is that you cant change the .Translucent property this way.

Comment: A good place to put it is in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions of appDelegate

Answer (score 16):

Swift 3 solution:

```
extension MFMailComposeViewController {
    override open func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
    }

    open override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        navigationBar.isOpaque = false
        navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
        navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to colorize only the cancel button a different color, say red and have the send button stay the white color?

Comment: Using iOS 11.3, various devices, this didn't work for me, but SoftDesigner's answer did

Answer (score 4):

For iOS8:

```
NSDictionary *navbarTitleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                            [UIColor whiteColor],UITextAttributeTextColor, 
                                            [UIColor blackColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, 
                                            [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(-1, 0)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset, nil];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:navbarTitleTextAttributes];
```

Or

```
navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor yellowColor] forKey:UITextAttributeTextColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

try this but one thing BarTintColor available only iOS7

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

This color is made translucent by default unless you set the translucent property to NO.

or try this link it will more helpful you

[Changing MFMailComposeViewController's toolbar color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634417/changing-mfmailcomposeviewcontrollers-toolbar-color)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    // Your usual code follows here ......
```

Answer (score 1):

@SoftDesigner's answer:

As of iOS 9:

```
[UINavigationBar appearance].tintColor = yourFavoriteColor;
```

does not work on the MFMailComposeViewController.

The rest of the answer works (I used it), but as far as I can tell you're stuck with Apple's colors for the nav bar buttons.

Hope this saves someone else some angst.

Answer (score 0):

First present the `MFMailComposeViewController` then change its `tintColor`

```
[self presentViewController:emailDialog animated:TRUE completion:nil];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:nil 
                                  forBarPosition:UIBarPositionTopAttached 
                                      barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm trying to change the background color not the background image... I tried ' [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:READER_NAVIGATION_BAR_BACKGROUND_COLOR];' after showing my emailDialog and doesn't work.

Comment: use setTintColor instead of BackgroundColor

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem that prevented me from setting the background colour. Turns out I had some other code elsewhere setting the background image to [UIImage new].

The following code fixed it:

```
 [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
 [[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:nil];
```