# Change UINavigationBar text colour on MFMailComposeViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

In my `AppDelegate.swift`, I added this line of code:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(hue: 0/360, saturation: 0/100, brightness: 91/100, alpha: 1)]
```

So that my navigationBars all show text in the colour I need.

I have since created a new `ContactUsViewController`, and added a contact form, where I use the `MFMailComposeViewController`. Everything works great, except, when the Mail ViewController shows, it shows the NavigationBar text colour as it should, but against a white background, so it's really hard to read.

[image]

Is there a way to keep my code on the `AppDelegate.swift` file so the rest of my app works as I want it, but amend the text colour just on the `MFMailComposeViewController` ?

Thanks and let me know if you need to see any of my code :)

Comment: tray to change the tintColor for your `MFMailComposeViewController`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547760/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-bar-background-color-not-changing-in-ios7